# Get the current weather by location in python

Tags: python, weather

Is there a plug and play python code to take a location and return information about the weather?  Something free.  Screen scraping isn't cutting it anymore since server side randomizes their html class keys and div anchor names to prevent exactly that sort of behavior.

Here's what I tried, it works, but the free tier is query rate limited.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib.request 
import sys 
import json 
API_KEY = "YOUR_API_KEY"
city_name = "Seattle%20Washington%20USA" 
try:
    ResultBytes = urllib.request.urlopen( 
        "http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=" + \ 
        str(API_KEY) + "&query=" + str(city_name))

    jsonData = json.load(ResultBytes) 
    locationStanza = jsonData.get('location', None)  
    currentStanza = jsonData.get('current', None)  
    cityname = str(locationStanza['name'])  
    regionname = str(locationStanza['region'])  
    country = str(locationStanza['country'])  
    location_val = str(cityname) + " " + str(regionname) + " " + str(country)  
    time_val = str(currentStanza['observation_time'])  
    info_val = str(currentStanza['weather_descriptions'][0])  
    centigrade_value = str(currentStanza['temperature'])  
    print(centigrade_value)
 
except urllib.error.HTTPError  as e: 
  ErrorInfo= e.read().decode()  
  print('Error code: ', e.code, ErrorInfo) 
  sys.exit() 
except  urllib.error.URLError as e: 
  ErrorInfo= e.read().decode()  
  print('Error code: ', e.code,ErrorInfo) 
  sys.exit()
```

Comment: `import current_weather`? Just kidding.

Comment: Will the user be supplying the place or will you define the place beforehand?

Comment: Use beautiful soup and a weather web site of your choice.

Answer (score 2):

Use `svn checkout http://python-weather-api.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ python-weather-api-read-only` to get the code from [python-weather-api](https://code.google.com/p/python-weather-api/)

I am using ubuntu so if you are using some other os check the link for instructions.

cd to `python-weather-api-read-only` then run `sudo python setup.py install`

You can get weather country code ID's from [here](https://www.edg3.co.uk/snippets/weather-location-codes/)

I made a simple function based on a docs example:

```
import pywapi
import string
def get_weather(loc_id):
    weather_com_result = pywapi.get_weather_from_weather_com(loc_id)
    yahoo_result = pywapi.get_weather_from_yahoo(loc_id)
    print "Weather.com says: It is " + string.lower(weather_com_result['current_conditions']['text']) + " and " +   weather_com_result['current_conditions']['temperature'] + "C now in Galway Ireland.\n\n"
    print "Yahoo says: It is " + string.lower(yahoo_result['condition']['text']) + " and " + yahoo_result['condition']['temp'] + "C now in Galway Ireland.\n\n"

In [2]: get_weather('EIXX0017')
Weather.com says: It is cloudy / windy and 11C now in Galway Ireland.

Yahoo says: It is partly cloudy and 12C now in Galway Ireland.
```

Took five minutes to find, install and make a simple function after searching  google.

If you want to accept user input make a dict of with countries/cities as keys and store codes as values.